# On how to have a negated $\eta$

Tags: fonts, symbols

In set theory one often uses `$\notin$` as with a slash through `$\in$`. How can I produce a similar slash through `$\eta$`?

Comment: `$\not\eta$` ?..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\not\mathrel{\eta}`, perhaps.

Comment: My proposal is `\mathord{\mkern-1mu\not\mathrel{\mkern1mu\eta}\mkern1mu}` Use `\mathrel` if it must be used as a relation symbol.

Comment: @egreg yes I was going to make an answer with space adjustments but one got posted then it was closed as dup..

Comment: It seems that these other suggestions require special packages.